# What test can I use for comparing data grouped in pairs?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, paired-data

<sup>(Apologies for the less than descriptive title; edits welcome, also for the tags.)</sup>

I ran a survey which contained questions of the following type (the specific example here is fabricated; it is irrelevant): each question presented the participant with a user interface. One element (a button) was left empty. Participants were asked to evaluate the appropriateness of two different button styles in that user interface on a Likert scale. The user interface in each question was different (e.g. login, forgot password, logout) but the two button styles were the same throughout (e.g. red and blue). For each participant, I have data of the following type:

|  | Blue | Red |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Login | 7 (extremely appropriate) | 1 (not appropriate at all) |
| Logout | 6 (appropriate) | 3 (not entirely appropriate) |
| ... | ... | ... |

What I am now interested in is whether there is a significant difference in the appropriateness of the two button styles depending on the type of user interface. For example: "Blue buttons are significantly more appropriate than red buttons for login interfaces than logout interfaces". I <s>know</s> think that I can use a T-test to check whether blue is more appropriate than red for login interfaces. But what kind of test can I use to compare the difference between blue and red from interface to interface?

Besides the individual measures for each pair of interfaces, I am also interested in an aggregate measure. All user interfaces in the survey came in pairs. So for "login" there is a "logout", for "apply" there is a "cancel", for "send" there is a "receive", etc. The aggregate measure I'm interested in is whether "Blue buttons are significantly more appropriate for login/apply/send than for logout/cancel/receive". The reason for this is that I am working with a hypothesis that assigns login/apply/send to one group and logout/cancel/receive to another (again, the UI example is fabricated, in the actual survey these groups make more sense). What kind of test should I use for this?

Comment: welcome to cv! your short example suggests that the answer for Red is always complementary to Blue : likert values add up to 8. Is this necessarily so, by design?

Comment: @Ute thanks! No, that was accidental. I have changed the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the site.

Sounds to me like you want some kind of regression, with "score" (1 to 7) as the dependent variable and color, interface, and their interaction as independent variables. There are two complications:

First: What type of regression? You say you "know" you can use a t-test. But that isn't clear. Using a t-test assumes that the Likert scale is interval or ratio level, that is, that the difference between (say) 1 and 2 is the same as between (say) 6 and 7. Lots of people do make this assumption, but it is not, strictly speaking, correct; at least, it's hard to know how reasonable it is.  If you are not willing to make this assumption, then you can use ordinal logistic regression.

Second, there may be person effects, which would mean that the errors are not independent. Suppose that Joe just rates things higher than Jill does, regardless of the thing in question. One way to deal with this is to use multilevel models, with person as a random effect. There are MLM for OLS type problems and also for ordinal logistic.

But it sounds like a fairly tricky problem and you might want to hire a consultant (not me, I'm retired). If you aren't very experienced with statistics, this is not a good starting place.

Comment: Thank you! I somehow did not think about using the interface itself as an independent variable.